# HTTP Error 508: Loop Detected python urllib.request

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, urllib

I'm scraping a website with the code bellow and after i run it two times the third show me an error of

> HTTP Error 508: Loop Detected

```
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)

liList=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'columns-list'})
links=[]
for a in liList.find_all('a'):

    req = Request(a.attrs['href'], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    data=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
    h=data.find("div",attrs={'class':'first-h2'})

    print(h.h2.text)
    print(data.find("h5"))
```

How to prevent this? sometimes it works and other it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's a kind of "Internal Server Error", which indicates that the server entered in a loop, as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/508

```
It indicates that the server terminated an operation because it encountered
an infinite loop while processing a request with "Depth: infinity". This
status indicates that the entire operation failed.
```

So, its a server error, not yours